# How can i check the type of an image?

Tags: c#, opencv

In my part of code sometimes I have:

```
Image<Gray, byte> imtemp = cap.QueryGrayFrame();
```

or

```
Image<Bgr, byte> imtemp = cap.QueryFrame();
```

depends if the video frame is grayscale or colorful.

Now in a function, I want to write a command to check if variable `imtemp` is BGR type or Gray. How should I write such if-statements?

pseudo code could be like:

```
if ( the imtemp is BGR) do
else if ( imtemo is grayscale) do....
```

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just check if `imtermp is Image<Gray, byte>` or `imtermp is Image<Bgr, byte>`?

Comment: yes,but how should I write its if-statement command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your if else like:

```
if ( imtemp is Image<Gray, byte>) 
{
   //The image is from QueryGrayFrame
}
else if ( imtermp is Image<Bgr, byte>) 
{
   //The image is from QueryFrame
}
```

Comment: yes,but what is the acceptable command of this check? { c# doesn't have any is command}

Comment: Did you try it?  Also C# does have [is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) operator.